# Why is custom template not seen as page with is_page()?

Tags: pages, templates

I created a couple of templates for a project, which is in fact a child theme of the [Contrast theme](http://themeforest.net/item/contrast/68089). In the Wordpress CMS, I can select the templates I created:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OLaz.png (Can't post image, I'm too much of a newbie the site says...)

In one of the functions of the theme (see background.php below), there is this check for conditions:

```
<?php if (is_page() || is_single()) { ?>
```

Which works on all my custom templates but two. I know for a fact that the two places where this fails are actually pages, but the value returned by `is_page()` is still empty, thus `false`.

What should I look for in order to make sure these two templates are taken as pages? Or is it something else that I should look for?

Below is the code for two templates. Keep in mind that I only touched the code relative to the content, not the if/elses at the beginning of the templates.

At the bottom of the page is included a file that makes that check for the `is_page()`. Code for that file below as well.

Textual Content Template (functional, returns a value for `is_page()`):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Textual Content Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        // transparent_layer
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '0')
        {
            if(option('transparent_layer') == '0')
            {
                $transparent = false;
            }
            elseif(option('transparent_layer') == '1')
            {
                $transparent = true;
            }
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '1')
        {
            $transparent = false;
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '2')
        {
            $transparent = true;
        }


        // content_position
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '0')
        {
            if(option('content_position') == '0')
            {
                $content_position = '0';
            }
            elseif(option('content_position') == '1')
            {
                $content_position = '1';
            }
            elseif(option('content_position') == '2')
            {
                $content_position = '2';
            }
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '1')
        {
            $content_position = '0';
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '2')
        {
            $content_position = '1';
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '3')
        {
            $content_position = '2';
        }


        //portrait_fit
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'portrait_fit')) == '1')
        {
            $portrait = '1';
        }
    ?>

    <!-- content start -->
    <div class="content">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <div class="sliderContent">
            <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <div class="content-body">
                <?php the_content(__('Read More &raquo;', THEMENAME)); ?>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <p><?php _e('Nothing found.', THEMENAME); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- content end -->

    <?php require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/includes/theme-background.php'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

News Template (not functional, returns no value for `is_page()`):

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: News Page
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
        // transparent_layer
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '0')
        {
            if(option('transparent_layer') == '0')
            {
                $transparent = false;
            }
            elseif(option('transparent_layer') == '1')
            {
                $transparent = true;
            }
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '1')
        {
            $transparent = false;
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'transparent_layer')) == '2')
        {
            $transparent = true;
        }


        // content_position
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '0')
        {
            if(option('content_position') == '0')
            {
                $content_position = '0';
            }
            elseif(option('content_position') == '1')
            {
                $content_position = '1';
            }
            elseif(option('content_position') == '2')
            {
                $content_position = '2';
            }
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '1')
        {
            $content_position = '0';
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '2')
        {
            $content_position = '1';
        }
        elseif(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'content_position')) == '3')
        {
            $content_position = '2';
        }


        // portrait_fit
        if(meta(array('id' => $post -> ID, 'meta' => 'portrait_fit')) == '1')
        {
            $portrait = '1';
        }
    ?>


    <!-- content start -->
    <div class="content">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

        <div class="sliderContent">

            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <div class="content-body news-items-list">
                <?php
                    // loop through posts in news category
                    // -1 means all posts... not really intuitive
                    // see http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/03/5-wordpress-queryposts-tips/
                    $query = array  (
                                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                        'category_name' => 'news'
                                    );
                    query_posts($query);
                    while(have_posts()) : the_post();

                    // get post raw date
                    $date = get_the_date();
                ?>
                    <a 
                        href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
                        class="news-link"
                        >
                        <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        <span class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
                    </a>

                <?php
                    endwhile;
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- content end -->

    <?php require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/assets/includes/theme-background.php'); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see, background.php is included at the bottom of these templates. This file comes from the parent theme, which I did not edit. Below is its code:

```
<!-- loading start -->
<div class="loading">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/images/loading.gif" alt ="Loading" />
</div>
<!-- loading end -->


<!-- background start -->
<div id="background">

        <?php if (is_page() || is_single()) { ?>

            <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '1') { ?>

                <style type="text/css">
                    #background { background: <?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_color')); ?>; }
                </style>

            <?php } elseif (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '2') { ?>

                <img src="<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_image')); ?>" alt="" class="background" />

            <?php } elseif (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '3') { ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var flashvars = { flv : '<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_flash_video')); ?>' };
                    var params = { wmode: 'transparent' };
                    swfobject.embedSWF('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/flash/background.swf', 'background', '100%', '100%', '9.0.0', 'expressInstall.swf', flashvars, params);
                </script>

            <?php } elseif (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '4') { ?>

                <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_google_maps_gradient')) == '1') { ?>
                <div class="gradient">
                    <div class="left">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="right">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_google_maps')); ?>"></iframe>

            <?php } elseif (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '5') { ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $.supersized({
                            slide_interval      : <?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_timeout')) ?>,
                            transition          : <?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_effect')) ?>,
                            transition_speed    : <?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_speed')) ?>,
                            slide_links         : 'blank',
                            slides              : [<?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_category_type')) == '1') {
                                                $slideshow_categories = '&slideshow-categories=' . meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_category')); }
                                                query_posts('post_type=slideshow' . $slideshow_categories. '&orderby=date&showposts=' . meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'slideshow_show_posts')));
                                                if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post();
                                                $slideshow_images = $slideshow_images . '{image : \'' . image(array('image' => get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID), 'tag' => false)) . '\'},';
                                                }} wp_reset_query(); echo substr($slideshow_images, 0, -1); ?>]
                        });
                    });
                </script>

                <div id="progress-back" class="load-item">
                    <div id="progress-bar"></div>
                </div>

            <?php } elseif (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background')) == '6') { ?>

                <video id="video" class="background">
                    <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_mp4_video')) != '') { ?>
                    <source src="<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_mp4_video')); ?>" type="video/mp4" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_webm_video')) != '') { ?>
                    <source src="<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_webm_video')); ?>" type="video/webm" />
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_ogv_video')) != '') { ?>
                    <source src="<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_ogv_video')); ?>" type="video/ogg" />
                    <?php } ?>
                </video>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var video = document.getElementById('video');

                    if (typeof video.loop == 'boolean') {
                        video.loop = true;
                    }

                    else {
                        video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
                        this.currentTime = 0;
                        this.play();
                        }, false);
                    }

                    video.play();
                </script>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php if (meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_image_pattern')) == '1') { ?>
                <div class="pattern pattern-0<?php echo meta(array('id' => $post->ID, 'meta' => 'post_background_pattern')); ?>">&nbsp;</div>
            <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
</div>
<!-- background end -->
```

Comment: Try dumping the $wp_query variable to see what is_$ condition is met.

Comment: Does `is_singular()` work?

Comment: @BrianFegter: actually, most is_$ conditions are false (they are at the bottom of the dump I obtained)

Comment: @toscho: no, I get the same results with that value

Comment: The only is_$ condition that is true is `is_category`

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code for this?

Comment: @EricHolmes: I updated my question with my code.

Comment: I'm not seeing `is_page()` or `is_single()` anywhere in there..

Comment: @EricHolmes: why would it be archive? In any case, I made two similar templates that do not work, one for news, another for portfolio. Neither of those return is_page() as true, and they are, since in the CMS I used add page to add them, I just selected the custom template.

Comment: @EricHolmes: as for the is_page(), that check is made by the included file at the bottom of the page, a file I did not modify. I'll add it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `query_posts($query);` in your second template, you overwrite the global variable that WordPress uses to return the correct values for the `is_` conditionals. You should basically *never* use `query_posts` in the template. For secondary loops, use a new instance of [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead.

Comment: A-ha! That was indeed my issue! THanks so much!